# Как понимать данные интервалы: (-10k, 0], (0, 5], (5, 10], (10, 10k] или (n, m], [n, m), (n, m), [n, m]

Tags: математика

Есть задача:

> Написать программу, которая определяет, что число *k* относиться к интервалу (-10k, 0], (0, 5], (5, 10], (10, 10k] или (n, m], [n, m), (n, m), [n, m]

Помогите разобраться, что обозначает данные интервалы?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Круглые скобки `(`, `)` обозначают, что граничное значение не включается в интервал
- Квадратные скобки `[`, `]` обозначают, что граничное значение включается в интервал

Иными словами

- x ∈ (m, n) ⇔ m < x < n
- x ∈ [m, n) ⇔ m ≤ x < n
- x ∈ (m, n] ⇔ m < x ≤ n
- x ∈ [m, n] ⇔ m ≤ x ≤ n

Comment: `k` обозначает 10^3 (т.е. тысячи)

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець, как я сразу не понял этого сокращения. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець это нетривиально, я даже сразу не понял и подумал, что в записи `(-10k, 0]` - это десять тысяч, а не `10*k`